# Eject iPhone from Mac via API

Tags: objective-c, macos, unmount

I am building a device control app for macOS.
I am able to unmount Disk-On-Keys and SSD cards via the APIs: `DADiskCreateFromIOMedia` & `DADiskUnmount`.

However, I can't use `DADiskCreateFromIOMedia` for iPhone as it doesn't have an `IOMedia`, or at least this is what I think.

Does anyone have a clue how I can eject an iPhone?
Any link, API, blog, resource will be helpful.

macOS: Ventura 13.2.1
Languages: C/C++/Objective-C